# Tweepy got TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Tags: python, virtualenv, tweepy

Hi !

I am experiencing an issue with the Tweepy function `search` and `search_users`: When I launch my little piece of code below:

```
auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(creds["consumer_key"], creds["consumer_secret"])
auth.secure = True
auth.set_access_token(creds["access_token"], creds["access_token_secret"])

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True,retry_count=10,retry_delay=5,retry_errors=5)
#The error is the same for 'search_users & 'search'
res = api.search_users(q="Hello",count=10)
res = api.search(q="Hello",count=10)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/projects/twitter/twitter/common/search.py", line 14, in searchUser
res = api.search_users(q="Hello",count=10)
File "/projects/twitter/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy-3.6.0-py3.5.egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 250, in _call
File "/projects/twitter/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy-3.6.0-py3.5.egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 214, in execute

TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Note: I am currently using `virtualenv`, but I don't think the issue is related to.

Note 2: The issue is the same on Tweepy versions `3.5` & `3.6`

Can someone help me to highlight what I did wrong ? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the full traceback, you'll see that the line in question is:

```py
elif self.retry_errors and resp.status_code not in self.retry_errors:
```

You set `retry_errors=5`, when initializing the [`API`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#API).
`retry_errors` should instead be an iterable of HTTP status codes to retry for.

Answer (score 0):

`Search_users` doesn't take that `count` argument. Just run `api.search_users(q="Hello")` instead and you should get back a list of users that match the string.

Comment: Actually, count argument exists :) You can see it on the program here: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py#L351